# Get directory of filename

Tags: c#, io

So I am wondering how do I get the directory of a file.

So if I want to find the directory of `C:\Directory\myfile.txt`

I would get `C:\Directory`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Path.GetDirectoryName` method

```
 var dirname = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
```

this will output `C:\Directory`

Don't forget to add the using `System.IO`